# How can I assign elements to a const char * array from a normal char array in a loop?

Tags: c, arrays

```
const char * pathArray[50];
char nextFile[35];

while(lastFile == 0) {
    file_descriptor = open(nextFile, O_RDWR);

    if (file_descriptor == -1){
        printf("Sorry, but %s could not be opened", nextFile);  
        exit(1);
    }

    nread = read (file_descriptor, buffer, 512);
    close(file_descriptor);

    if(strstr(buffer, "LAST_FILE") != NULL){
        lastFile++;
        break;
    }

    printf("CURRENT FILE: %s\n", nextFile);
    printf("\n NEXT FILE:");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", nextFile); 
    pathIndex++;
    pathArray[pathIndex] = nextFile;

    for(i = 0; i < pathIndex; i++) { 
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, pathArray[i]);        
    }
} //end while
```

What I hadn't anticipated is that pathArray[pathIndex] = nextFile; assigns the address of nextFile to that index, so the entire array gets changed whenever nextFile does. I'm very new to C and have tried a lot of things and found a lot of problems getting the whole file name in (many of the file names have spaces in them so it's supposed to be read until the user hits enter, and the above was the way I found to prevent the file name from being cut off at the first space).

I also tried adding a char * otherArray[50] so that I could use strcpy, but changing my assignment to:

```
    strcpy(otherArray[pathIndex], nextFile);
    pathArray[pathIndex] = otherArray[pathIndex];
```

causes a segmentation fault. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you really want to achieve, but from what I do understand you are pretty much on the wrong track. Why do you need the `const char *` variable at the top, why don't you use `char *` without `const`?

Comment: assigning one array to another is not what you are intneding to do, I believe. Try `strcpy(pathArray[pathIndex], nextfile);` You also need to allocate the correct memory needed in your `pathArray[index];` That being said, there is a lot that does not make much sense here.

Comment: It causes segmentation faults for some reason (when I try to use strcpy), and when I don't use strcpy, it has the same issue. EDIT: Sorry, I posted before bentank commented. How do I allocate the correct amount of memory for pathArray[pathIndex]?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! EDIT: strdup(nextFile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this

```
char *pathArray[50];
char nextFile[35];
int pathIndex = 0;

// Do something to read into nextFile?
// create new mem for string and assign pointer to new string in your array
pathArray[pathIndex++] = strdup(nextFile);
```

The reason it is seg faulting is due to not allocating any memory for the string inside your array.

From strdup man page:

> The  strdup()  function  returns  a  pointer  to  a  new string which is a duplicate of the string s.  Memory for the new string is
>          obtained with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3).

Note: you are required to free the newly created copy.

Comment: `pathIndex` should be `size_t` instead of `int`, really.

Comment: @IskarJarak, it does not matter at all in this case. Unless INT_MAX was less than 50... And given int must be 16 bits or greater, that is not the case.

Comment: I'm well aware "it doesn't matter in this case" but it is better practice to use `size_t`, and I think your answer would be improved by it.

Comment: Sure, it couldn't hurt.